# How does pgAdmin connect to the server?

Tags: postgresql, protocols, pgadmin

I've started to read about protocols (HTTP/TCP/IP etc.).

I have a few questions.

How does pgAdmin connect to the server? Which protocol does it use? Am I able to connect to the DB server via cmd? How do drivers connect to the DB server?

Answer (score 1):

They use the [well documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/protocol.html) PostgreSQL frontend/backend protocol.